# In Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Michael's Hartl's), toy_app won't produce a :Production group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Chapter 2.1 of Michael Hartl's book Ruby on Rails tutorial (Rails 5), I run the scaffold... all is well, except when I look at the Gem file to compare gems, some are a bit different versions, I can live with that, but the Production Group was never created.  The Development and Test Group are there... but no Production Group.

Something is preventing it from being created with the PG gem.
Any help...much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `scaffold` command is used for generating boilerplate controller/view/helper/model code. You may run this many times per project.

The `rails new` command generates the `Gemfile` and puts the gems inside of it. You run this once per project. Since you're mentioning issues with a `production` group I'm assuming the issue you're having is related to a `Gemfile` `group :production do` block.

By default, no `production` group is created in your `Gemfile` when you run `rails new`. If you look at his tutorial here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-planning_the_application

```
Next, we’ll use a text editor to update the Gemfile needed by Bundler 
with the contents of Listing 2.1.
```

You need to manually create the production group and place the `gem 'pg'` line of code inside of it like the listing.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I understand that Scaffold "should" create a PRODUCTION group, but when I run Scaffold it never does. I have to manually add in the PRODUCTION group then Bundle "PG" to get it to work right.  So I think there is something in an option file that stops PRODUCTION group from being created... just don't know where?

Comment: Steve, I should have been more clear. When I say no production group is created "by default", I mean at all, unless you're using a custom generator (the tutorial does not). Scaffold doesn't update the Gemfile either; it generates a controller, views, helper, and sometimes other files depending on your configuration (js, css, json, spec files, etc). You have to manually edit the Gemfile per the snippet I called out in my answer, and add that block yourself.

Comment: For further clarification, scaffold shouldn't ever update the Gemfile. You can read more about scaffolding here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I figured that was what the author meant - it just wasnt' spelled out very clearly.